# How to programmatically schedule system wake up using system preferences on a Mac?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, wakeup

I would like to programmatically wake up a Mac. I started off by using IOPMSchedulePowerEvent, however, that method requires admin access and privileged helpers. I've implemented and it works but is way too complicated.

I've looked around for a better approach and found that you can schedule the system to wake up by going to, System Preferences -> Energy Saver -> Schedule. Is there a way to programmatically schedule a wake up time using this method?

Thanks.

Edit: I understand the system requires admin access to schedule system wakeup and sleep time. That is ok. I would like to be able to do this programmatically. Having the user authorize the functionality is ok provided that they are only asked once. Subsequent requests to set the system wakeup time should not have to require user authorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `IOPMSchedulePowerEvent` is the right thing to do.  However, if you create a privileged helper tool you only need to prompt the user once for his/her password.  Apple's [BetterAuthorizationSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/BetterAuthorizationSample/) code provides an example of how to do this; there's also a third-party modification, [AuthorizedTasksInCocoa](http://www.sheepsystems.com/sourceCode/authTasksCocoa.html), which might be a bit easier to use (I haven't tried it).

Comment: @Nicholas, I have already implemented a helper using BAS, however, BAS uses launchd to run the helper. By doing so, launchd requires the helper daemon to be installed in /Library/LaunchDaemons. This is the Apple approved way but for the Mac App store, Apple does not like it because it breaks one of their rules about file application file location.

Comment: Yup, you can't do this if you want to submit to the Mac App Store.  This is by design and there's no way around it.  File a bug with Apple if this is a problem for you and maybe, someday, they'll change the rules.  (Other applications which use authorization have separate versions for the Mac App Store that remove the authorization feature.)

Comment: Well, I know that waking the system up from sleep is possible because there are alarm clock applications in the store that does it (ex. Aurora). The Aurora application requires one admin authentication and uses a helper tool to wake the system from sleep. I don't understand how they can get a way with not using launchd.

Comment: You can create a setuid helper inside your app bundle (like MoreAuthSample) but that also breaks the App Store guidelines.  If the app store version of Aurora does it (I'm not willing to spend $10 to find out) then it's breaking the rules.  The non-App Store version of Aurora installs a setuid helper tool in `/Library/Application Support/Aurora`.

Comment: I bought a version of Aurora from the App Store to figure out how they do it and they do indeed install a helper tool in /Library/Application Support/Aurora when the application launches. Their helper is an agent that creates a menu bar app and is deleted from /Library/Application Support/Aurora when the menu bar is closed. So Aurora is breaking the rules using a method that Apple does not like. What should I do? Should I use the BAS approach that I've already have working or fall back and use MAS, a deprecated method that Apple does not like? Or should I use neither?

Comment: I'd say neither; either don't sell your app through the Mac App Store or have a separate version that has the additional feature (unless it's essential to your app).  You could potentially transfer registrations from one to the other like this: http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/1678/this-app-is-your-app

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full answer for you, but this should help immensely:
http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/PowerManagement/PowerManagement-211/pmset/pmset.c

What you'll want to do is schedule a `kIOPMAutoWake`. Find that constant (not a variation thereof) in the code and start reading. It's not THAT long.

You can probably even use `pmset` directly, but that would be pretty inelegant.

As for elevating, Apple talks about it in [Secure Coding Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/AccessControl.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is intended to require admin access.  For example, the options in System Preferences -> Energy Saver -> Schedule are unavailable unless you're logged in as an admin or have authenticated to System Preferences as an admin.  If you found a way to do it without any special privs, I'd expect Apple to regard that as a security bug, and fix it (thus breaking your program).

Comment: ok admin access is required but do you know a way to programatically access the system sleep and wake up scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule wake up events with IOPMSchedulePowerEvent through the power manager. You may be able to schedule an immediate wake up. pmset is a command line wrapper for the power manager. You can also prevent sleep with IOCancelPowerChange in certain cases.

You may be able to prevent sleep or wake up by generating a mouse or key event. One way to generate events is with CGPostKeyboardEvent.

==>Normal sleep is different from clamshell closed sleep. To affect the latter you must write a kernel extension like Insomnia.